# Saving 'file.write' data "on the fly" for live data viewing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a timer in my while loop.
So far I've gotten it to save my data when the loop ends since I have my file.close() outside of the loop.

But I want the data to be saved 'on the fly' so I can implement a live graph.
Seems like an easy fix but don't know where to look.

Example:

```
import time
timeout = time.time() + 10
file = open("testfile.txt", "w")

while True:
    test = 0
    if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
        break
    test = test - 1

    file.write("1")
    file.write(",2\n")
    print("saving data...")

    time.sleep(1)

file.close()
```

Comment: `file.flush()` will write any pending I/O to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `flush()` method after the `write()` methods.

However I really recommend using Python's `logging` module for this. I think it it better suited for this use-case - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html